# How to add Different Suffix at two Different google gauges

Tags: php, charts, raspberry-pi, google-visualization, gauge

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running a lamp server and reading data from a AM2302 sensor the data is store at mysql database and then displaying in a webpage trough php file.

the main questions is that wanna to assign different suffix at two google gauges ( one for the temperature and one for the humidity), but is not working as desire, when I refresh the page it show zero value with the suffix that I wanna for each one, but in the next second when show it the data form database It just display the same suffix in the two gauges.

And they are show it one on top the another, how can I putting side by side

here is a picture:

[image: here is a picture:]

and I wanna these results

[image: and I wanna these result]

here is the code form my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Medidor Temperatura, Humedad</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var dataHumid = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Humid', 0],
      ]);

    var dataTemp = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['Temp', 0]
      ]);

    var optionsHumid = {
      width: 170, height: 170,
      redFrom: 0, redTo: 33,
      yellowFrom: 33, yellowTo: 66,
      greenFrom: 66, greenTo: 100,
      majorTicks: ['0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90', '100'],
      minorTicks: 10
        };
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
       suffix: '%',
       fractionDigits: 1
       });
       formatter.format(dataHumid, 1);

    var optionsTemp = {
      width: 170, height: 170,
      redFrom: 30, redTo: 45,
      yellowFrom:24, yellowTo: 30,
      greenFrom: 12, greenTo: 24,
      majorTicks: ['0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90', '100'],
      minorTicks: 10
        };

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
       suffix: 'h',
       fractionDigits: 1
       });
       formatter.format(dataTemp, 1);

    var chartHumid = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById("chart_Humid"));
    var chartTemp = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById("chart_Temp"));

    chartHumid.draw(dataHumid, optionsHumid,formatter);
    chartTemp.draw(dataTemp, optionsTemp, formatter);

    setInterval(function() {
        var JSON=$.ajax({
            url:"sensores.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false}).responseText;
        var Respuesta=jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);
      dataHumid.setValue(0, 1,Respuesta[0].humidity);
      formatter.format(dataHumid, 1);
      chartHumid.draw(dataHumid, optionsHumid);
    }, 1300);

 setInterval(function() {
        var JSON=$.ajax({
            url:"sensores.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false}).responseText;
        var Respuesta=jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);

      dataTemp.setValue(0, 1,Respuesta[0].temperature);
      formatter.format(dataTemp, 1);
      chartTemp.draw(dataTemp, optionsTemp);
    }, 1300);

  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
       <div class="gauge" id="chart_Humid"></div>       <div class="gauge" id="chart_Temp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I edit the question to show the result I got, Now I am able to display the data from two sensors. 
[image]

thanks for the help of the user 
WhiteHat

Comment: Thanks but howbi do it. I am really noob with these coding stuff

Comment: most important to me is how add the suffix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add the rows to one data table and draw one chart,
you'll get two gauge charts in row, rather than *one on top of the another*...

however, after reading the question closer,
you will need to draw two different charts,
because the options are not the same for both.

first, to get the two charts in a row, rather than a column,
you can add the following css to the `.gauge` class...

```
.gauge {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

this will cause the `<div>` elements to display inline with one another.

---

as for the suffix, need to use unique names for the formatters.
above, the same variable is used for both --> `var formatter`

when the second is created, it overrides the suffix for the first.
instead of...

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  suffix: '%',
  fractionDigits: 1
});
formatter.format(dataHumid, 1);

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  suffix: 'h',
  fractionDigits: 1
});
formatter.format(dataTemp, 1);
```

we'll use...

```
var formatHumid = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  suffix: '%',
  fractionDigits: 1
});
formatHumid.format(dataHumid, 1);

var formatTemp = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  suffix: 'h',
  fractionDigits: 1
});
formatTemp.format(dataTemp, 1);
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['gauge']
}).then(function () {
  var dataHumid = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Humid', 0]
  ]);

  var dataTemp = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Temp', 0]
  ]);

  var optionsHumid = {
    width: 170, height: 170,
    redFrom: 0, redTo: 33,
    yellowFrom: 33, yellowTo: 66,
    greenFrom: 66, greenTo: 100,
    majorTicks: ['0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90', '100'],
    minorTicks: 10
  };

  var formatHumid = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    suffix: '%',
    fractionDigits: 1
  });
  formatHumid.format(dataHumid, 1);

  var optionsTemp = {
    width: 170, height: 170,
    redFrom: 30, redTo: 45,
    yellowFrom: 24, yellowTo: 30,
    greenFrom: 12, greenTo: 24,
    majorTicks: ['0','10','20','30','40','50','60','70','80','90', '100'],
    minorTicks: 10
  };

  var formatTemp = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    suffix: 'h',
    fractionDigits: 1
  });
  formatTemp.format(dataTemp, 1);

  var chartHumid = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById("chart_Humid"));
  var chartTemp = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById("chart_Temp"));

  chartHumid.draw(dataHumid, optionsHumid);
  chartTemp.draw(dataTemp, optionsTemp);

  setInterval(function() {
    /*
    var JSON=$.ajax({
      url:"sensores.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false}).responseText;
    var Respuesta=jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);
    dataHumid.setValue(0, 1, Respuesta[0].humidity);
    */
    dataHumid.setValue(0, 1, 74.9);
    formatHumid.format(dataHumid, 1);
    chartHumid.draw(dataHumid, optionsHumid);
  }, 1300);

  setInterval(function() {
    /*
    var JSON=$.ajax({
      url:"sensores.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false}).responseText;
    var Respuesta=jQuery.parseJSON(JSON);
    dataTemp.setValue(0, 1, Respuesta[0].temperature);
    */
    dataTemp.setValue(0, 1, 27.5);
    formatTemp.format(dataTemp, 1);
    chartTemp.draw(dataTemp, optionsTemp);
  }, 1300);
});
```

```css
.gauge {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="gauge" id="chart_Humid"></div>
<div class="gauge" id="chart_Temp"></div>
```

Comment: it works like a charm, the suffix are displaing as desire, but the part for putting in the gauges in row is not working for me. I think i dont know how to used. because it appear to be separate from the other code

Comment: add the above css code inside a `<style>` tag in the head of your html...

Comment: you save me from hours of failed work. many, many thanks bro. Thumbs UP

Comment: Hey WhiteHat it is possible that you can help me, with the current configuration to display the data in the google area chart in order to display historical data using the dateandtime from my database?

Comment: possibly, have you added a question somewhere?

Comment: let me do it now and will post he link here

Comment: here is the link about these question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54832629/how-to-display-historical-temperature-humidity-google-chart-area-pi3